# Gulp - output or log specific line(s) of stream

Tags: npm

I am trying to learn to use Gulp. Uglify is currently failing, as I obviously have some malformed javascript in 1 of the .js files for minification.

the error is:

```
[00:20:49] GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 59201, col: 49, pos: 3171588)
```

The question is, how can I somehow output line 59201 of the stream (& perhaps a couple of lines before and after), so that I can identify the offending javascript?

---

in case anyone is interested in the function using uglify:

```
gulp.task('html', function(cb){
    pump([gulp.src('index.html'),
        useref(),
        gulpIf('*.js', uglify()),
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - not the cleverest - I was thinking the stream had the html, css and js data in it, but the call to gulp-if after useref means it is only the js in the steam generating the error, and I can just pipe to gulp.dest, and then open the JS in a text editor and goto specified line number!

```
pump([gulp.src('index.html'),
    useref(),
    gulp.dest('dist')], cb);
```

the problem turned out to be an arrow `()=>` function - obviously not yet supported.

Comment: The hint about arrow functions not being supported saved my day. Thanks!